# GWT Super Dev mode and in production

Tags: eclipse, gwt

I have a GWT application. My development environement is win7+Eclipes+Google plugin for Eclipse+J2SE8.

In Eclipse, when I run in super dev mode, everything works as expected.

But when I install tomcat8, and put war file generated in eclipse to webapps in tomcat, the gwt seems does not function. Any hints for GWT production mode, my final aim is to put war file in Ubuntu.

Juhani

Comment: Any logs from anywhere? There must be an error somewhere. What do you mean by "seems not to function" - the app doesn't start? Super dev mode doesn't work? Something else?

Comment: What does `the gwt seems does not function` means? Any errors in logfile?

Comment: Hi: in eclipse, if I run super dev mode, everything fine and dynamic dialog happens. After I shut down super dev mode, I put war file into tomcat webapps, only static text is there, dynamic dialog does not appear. When Boris the Spider and Jens means log file, do you mean log file in tomcat?